Weird error in "aligned" with package "mathtools"
I get some error while using the "aligned" environment and the "mathtools" package together. See the code below.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}&A=B\\
&C=D'.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*} 
\end{document}

I am working on overleaf, and it produces an error message saying
"Missing control sequence inserted.
Missing } inserted." in line 7,
and saying
"Extra }, or forgotten $." in line 8.
If I change the "D'" into "D" there is no error. If I remove the "mathtools" package there is no error. If I delete the first line "&A=B" there is no error. If I start a new line at "&A=B" there is no error.
I have no idea why this is the case, maybe it is because of overleaf? But on my local TexShop (latest version) the same thing happens.
(Of course the error is easily fixed by starting a new line at "&A=B" without changing the content, but I just want to know why.)

aligned takes an optional argument for vertical alignment. The default aligned has an issue such that if the first item of the aligned fx is [x] it eats it as the optional argument. mathtools fixes this such that it does not look for an optional argument if there is at least a space after \begin{aligned}. That code that then looks for the optional argument, does not expect to find a & at that point either.

@campa Look at what is around that line. They mess with \@xargdef

It's truly better to avoid such input style.
Since the beginning, aligned had to solve a problem: [ might the first math item inside aligned (as opposed to the bracket introducing the optional argument). In 2019, amsmath was slightly changed so something like
\begin{aligned}
[A]&=B \\
C&=D
\end{aligned}

or
\begin{aligned} [A]&=B
C&=D
\end{aligned}

(note the space in the second case) were flagged with a warning
Package amsmath Warning: Bracket group [A] at formula start!
(amsmath)                It could be a misspelled positional argument.
(amsmath)                If it belongs to the formula add a \relax in
(amsmath)                front to hide it on input line 16.

but the output is as expected in either case, so long that there is at least an intervening space (or newline) between \begin{aligned} and the bracket.
mathtools tried to avoid even the warning, but, as you discovered, its strategy can fail even when there's no [ to be careful about!
Fix: redefine aligned in an even safer way.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\NewEnvironmentCopy{alignedoriginal}{aligned}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{aligned}{!O{c}b}
 {\alignedoriginal[#1]#2\endalignedoriginal}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\begin{aligned}&A=B\\
&C=D'.
\end{aligned}
\\
\begin{aligned} [A]&=B\\
C&=D'.
\end{aligned}
\\
\begin{aligned}
[A]&=B\\
C&=D'.
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}

No warning, output as expected in every case.

But, for your own sanity, always type the contents of aligned on lines of their own.

Thanks! I was not aware of this subtlety before. Will be careful about this in the future.
